# Structural typing in Scala: use abstract type in refinement

Tags: scala, structural-typing

Say I have the following code:

```
class Bar { def bar(b:Bar):Boolean = true }
def func(b:Bar) = b.bar(b)
```

The above works fine. The class `Bar` is defined in a 3rd party library and there are several similar classes, each with a `bar` method, for example

```
class Foo { def bar(f:Foo):Boolean = false }
```

Instead of writing `func` for each such class, I want to define `func` using generic type `B`  as long at it has a `bar` method of the correct signature.

I tried the following but it gives me an error:

```
def func[B <: {def bar(a:B):Boolean}](b:B) = b.bar(b) // gives error
```

The error I get is:

```
<console>:16: error: Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to 
an abstract type defined outside that refinement
def func[B <: {def bar(a:B):Boolean}](b:B) = b.bar(b)
                       ^
```

However, if I do the following, the method definition works but invocation gives an error:

```
def func[B <: {def bar(a:Any):Boolean}](b:B) = b.bar(b)

func(new Bar) 

<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
found   : Bar
required: B
          func(new Bar)
               ^
```

Is there any way to do what I want without changing the code of `Bar`?

Answer (score 2):

It is enought know problem with abstract type defined outside structural type for method parameter. Second your approach doesn't work because method signatures is not equal (looks like method overloading).

I propose use workaround. Functional approach of method definition, because Function1[-T1, +R] is known type:

```
class Bar { def bar : Bar => Boolean = _ => true }
class Foo { def bar : Foo => Boolean = _ => false }

def func[T <: { def bar : T => Boolean } ](b: T): Boolean = b.bar(b)

func(new Bar)
func(new Foo)
```

Cons & Pros **functional type** VS **method type** definition [here](http://cogita-et-visa.blogspot.com/2013/07/functional-desing-in-scala-function.html)